# Highcharts stock how to set default or max xaxis tick amount?

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts stock to plot a candlestick chart, how can I set the default x-axis tick amount to a specific number?
[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-test-xq04c?file=/src/components/StockVue.vue)
In the example Highstock plots all data at the beginning, I want to limit the initial x-axis tick size to 60, and drag the chart to see the rest data, what can I do?

Comment: Would you like to set the xAxis tick amount as 60 or display 60 points from the Volume series?

Comment: I'd like to set the xAxis initial amount as 60.

Comment: to be sure that we are on the same page - there is documentation of the xAxis tick amount - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickAmount and to me, the description of your requirement is not clear. Would you like to limit the initial amount of points for the volume series?